# Implementing PCIe Linux device driver (want to access my card registers from kernel driver)

Tags: linux-kernel, pci

I'm writing a device driver to access the memory in a FPGA on a PCIe card.
The card boots and is probed/found :-

/proc/iomem

```
80000000-840fffff : PCI Bus #03
  80000000-83ffffff : 0000:03:00.0
  84000000-840fffff : 0000:03:00.0
```

So reading ldd/etc I coded up a call to `request_mem_region` at the `80000000`, and requested a pointer to it via `ioremap_nocache`

1) Do I need to `request_mem_region` as well as a `ioremap_nocache`, cant I use just the latter?

/proc/iomem After `insmod` my device driver :-

```
80000000-840fffff : PCI Bus #03
  80000000-83ffffff : 0000:03:00.0
    80000000-8003ffff : fp2
  84000000-840fffff : 0000:03:00.0
```

2) Doesnt look quite right to me...?

Anyway, reads don't work *(its not coded like below, it has checks etc)*:-

```
#define BAR_ADDR 0x80000000
void *base = ioremap_nocache(BAR_ADDR, 0x40000);
void *address = base + KNOWN_REG_LOCATION;
int data = ioread32(address);
printk("fp2: address:0x%08x, data:0x%08x\n", address, data);
```

Outputs :-

```
address:0xfd500000, data:0xffffffff
```

I can read the `x80000000+KNOWN_REG_LOCATION` from mmap userspace.

3) I've tried `__raw_readl`/`readl` with no luck as well.

4) Can I just read at the currently mapped address `x80000000`?

Comment: Your .tar file requires a password . It would be helpful to review code.

Comment: I think your comment should be directed @willtake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ian,

I wrote a PCI driver for a device ([full source](http://www.rtd.com/software/DM/DM7820/linux/DM7820_Linux_V01.00.01.tar.gz)).  The mapping of the register space should be the same though.  Here is how I do it.

```
dm7820_device->pci[region].virt_addr = ioremap_nocache(address, length);
if (dm7820_device->pci[region].virt_addr == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "%s: ERROR: BAR%u remapping FAILED\n",
        &((dm7820_device->device_name)[0]), region);
    dm7820_release_resources();
    return -ENOMEM;
}

if (request_mem_region(address, length, &((dm7820_device->device_name)[0])) == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "%s: ERROR: I/O memory range %#lx-%#lx allocation FAILED\n",
        &((dm7820_device->device_name)[0]), address, (address + length - 1));
    dm7820_release_resources();
    return -EBUSY;
}
```

The address and length values are returned from `pci_resource_start()` and `pci_resource_length()` calls.

Then you can access it using `ioread32()` using `dm7820_device->pci[region].virt_addr + <register offset>`

Let me know if you have any questions.