# Do I need to "enable" a PCIe memory region in a Linux 3.12 driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I have code, called from the probe() function of my PCIe driver (loosely based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195061/32836)):

**EDIT:** *Based on [Andreas Bombe's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23418449/32836) response, I changed the code to use `pci_iomap()`, but I'm still experience the system hang*

```
static my_pci_dev pci_dev; /* local structure */
static int pci_setup_region(struct pci_dev *dev)
{
    int bar = 0;

    pci_dev.physical.addr = pci_resource_start(dev, bar);
    pci_dev.physical.size = pci_resource_len(dev, bar);

    pci_dev.virtual.addr = pci_iomap(dev, bar, pci_dev.physical.size);
    if (NULL == pci_dev.virtual.addr) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    } else {
        pci_dev.virtual.size = pci_dev.physical.size;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Virtual address: %p", pci_dev.virtual.addr);
    if (request_mem_region(pci_dev.physical.addr, pci_dev.physical.size, DEVICE_NAME) == NULL) {
        pci_release_resources();
        return -EBUSY;
    } else {
        pci_dev.physical.allocated = 1;
    }

    /* Test it out! */
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Trying to read data.\n");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Copied chip-id data:%08x", ioread8(pci_dev.virtual.addr));
    return 0;
}
```

But the kernel just hangs at the call to `ioread8()`.

**Am I doing something wrong? Or do I need to look to hardware?**

Here is the output on a clean boot of the system for `lspci -v` and `cat /proc/iomem`:

```
root@socfpga:~# lspci -v
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Altera Corporation Device e000 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: fast devsel
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00000000-00000fff
    Memory behind bridge: c0000000-c00fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000-000fffff
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [200] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1172 Rev=0 Len=044 <?>

01:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: Altera Corporation Device e002 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Altera Corporation Device e002
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 75
    Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [200] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1172 Rev=0 Len=044 <?>
    Kernel modules: test-pci
```

The memory comes up `[disabled]`: **do I have to enable it?**

```
root@socfpga:~# cat /proc/iomem 
00000000-3fffffff : System RAM
  00008000-006fa7d3 : Kernel code
  00754000-007d8c23 : Kernel data
c0000000-cfffffff : ALTERA PCIE RP MEM
  c0000000-c00fffff : PCI Bus 0000:01
    c0000000-c001ffff : 0000:01:00.0
d0000000-dfffffff : ALTERA PCIE RP PREF MEM
ff200000-ff20000f : csr
ff200010-ff20008f : vector_slave
ff210000-ff21003f : ff210000.chipidbridge0
ff280000-ff283fff : Cra
ff702000-ff703fff : /soc/ethernet@ff702000
ff704000-ff704fff : /soc/dwmmc0@ff704000
ff705000-ff705fff : ff705000.spi
ffa00000-ffa00fff : ff705000.spi
ffb40000-ffb4fffe : /soc/usb@ffb40000
ffc00000-ffc00fff : c_can_platform
ffc02000-ffc0201f : serial
ffc04000-ffc04fff : /soc/i2c@ffc04000
ffd02000-ffd02fff : /soc/wd@ffd02000
ffe01000-ffe01fff : /soc/amba/pdma@ffe01000
fff00000-fff00fff : fff00000.spi
ffff0000-ffffffff : /soc/sram@ffff0000
root@socfpga:~#
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You definitely have to enable it. These are the basic steps:

```
pci_enable_device(dev);
pci_request_regions(dev, "driver/device name");
bar0 = pci_iomap(dev, 0, 0);
x = ioread(bar0 + offset);  /* there you are */
```

Error checking is required for all the `pci_*` calls. If the device needs to do DMA you also need to call `pci_set_master` and `pci_set_dma_mask`.

To elaborate, bypassing the PCI kernel code and directly ioremapping the BARs may have worked a long time ago. I'm not sure if it is even legal anymore in current code but it certainly isn't advisable.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the antiquity of my code; didn't realize there was an updated interface. +1 for `pci_iomap()`: looking forward to testing it.

Comment: Tried your suggestion with no success.  Thinking it might be hardware.

Comment: Still haven't tried the `pci_request_regions()` interface, board hung on the other side of the city.

Answer (score 3):

To Enable the memory you can try out the below command directly.

`setpci -s <BUS_ADDR> COMMAND=0x02
-s      : Used for device selection
COMMAND : Asks for the word-sized command register, 0x02 is to enable memory`

`lspci Output :
0000:01:00.0 RAM memory: Xilinx Corporation Default PCIe endpoint ID
0001:02:00.0 Memory controller: Xilinx Corporation Device 8011
Example : setpci -s 0001:02:00.0 COMMAND=0x02`

Comment: Thank God you answered.  I've been waiting in front of this page for 4 years.