# How to access PCI memory from Linux kernel space by memory mapping (Kernel 3.14)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, pci

I'm looking for a way to access the memory space of an PCI device (explicit BAR2 and BAR3) without using DMA and IO-mapping. I have read much documentations but I never saw a flowchart or a step by step how to. So all my tries aren't successful.

These are the steps inside `pci_probe` I actually try:

1. `data = kzalloc( sizeof(*data) , GFP_KERNEL );`
2. `pci_set_drvdata(pdev, data);`
3. `pci_enable_device(pdev);`

Now is the question what is the correct address to access `BAR2+offset` using `writeb` or `readb`? Or is there a another function to read/write from this space?

---

PS: An similar question regarding `iomap` was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058353/address-mapping-of-pci-memory-in-kernel-space).

Comment: You cannot access anything without mapping it. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The goal is to access memory spaces on the PCI device for fast data exchange. I know that I need to map the addresses. But I read that there are two different types of mapping. IO-mapping to reach IO space und Memory-mapping to reach memory space. I know the way to reach mem-space via io mapping but now I'm looking for the faster way to do it via memory mapping.

Comment: On x86(-64) you can only map I/O BARs via I/O mapping and memory BARs via memory mapping as far as I'm aware. Other architectures don't necessarily have a distinction and their implementations may use memory-mapping for I/O ranges (e.g. PPC).

Comment: OK. And how to map memory BARs via memory mapping?

Comment: `pcim_iomap_regions()` is your helper. If you asking about **memory** connected via PCI bus, then you perhaps have to use `pci_resource_*()` in conjunction with `memremap()`.

Comment: `void *memremap(resource_size_t offset, size_t size, unsigned long flags);`is that I'm looking for. But it seems to me that this function is not supported by Kernel 3.14 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After heavy researching, I found a way and to read and write to PCI `BAR2`. It seems that `ioremap`, `pci_ioremap_bar` or `memremap()` (Kernel 4.3+) allows CPU caching the data transferred between PCI device and Kernel space memory. This causes corrupt data. But I don't know where it finally come from.

The approach to solve this issue uses `ioremap_nocache` from `io.h`. The following code shows the PCI probe function.

```
static int
_pci_probe ( struct pci_dev *pdev,
             const struct pci_device_id *ent )
{
  int ret = 0;
  int i;
  unsigned long *pbas2addr;
  u8  buf8;
  u8 *mem8;

  buf8  = 0xF0;
  // put mem8 to the heap and initialize them with zeros
  mem8 = kcalloc((0x020000),sizeof(u8), GFP_KERNEL);

  // enabling the device
  ret = pci_enable_device(pdev);
  if( ret )
  {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to enable PCI device.\n");
    goto no_enable;
  }

  // take ownership of pci related regions
  pci_request_regions(pdev, "expdev");

  // checking if PCI-device reachable by checking that BAR0 is defined and
  // memory mapped
  if( !(pci_resource_flags(pdev,0) & IORESOURCE_MEM) )
  {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Incorrect BAR configuration.\n");
    ret = -ENODEV;
    goto bad_bar;
  }

  // remap BAR2 avoiding the use of CPU cache
  pbas2addr = ioremap_nocache(pci_resource_start(pdev,2),
                              pci_resource_len(pdev,2));

  printk(KERN_INFO "BAR2 Addr: %p\n",pbas2addr);
  printk(KERN_INFO "BAR2 len:  %x\n",(int)pci_resource_len(pdev,2));

  // write something to BAR2
  buf8  = 0xF0;
  for ( i = 0x000000; i<0x020000; i++ )
  {
    *((u8*)pbas2addr+i) = buf8; // it's important to cast the pointer
  }

  // read back
  buf8 = 0;
  for ( i = 0x000000; i<0x020000; i++ )
  {
    mem8[i] = *((u8*)pbas2addr+i);
  }

  return 0;

bad_bar:
  pci_disable_device(pdev);
no_enable:

  return ret;
}
```

Additionally:

1. The access of the mapped memory using `iowrite` doesn't work stable. Sometimes artefactual crap are found on the PCI `BAR2` memory. Maybe there are hold sequences coming with this command. I don't know.
2. In my case some address ranges of the `BAR2` memory needs to be write twice. I think this is a special behaviour of this device.
3. In my case not all address ranges can be reached with 32-bit access. I think this is a special behaviour of this device too.

Comment: I would recommend to look at [mei: simplify error handling via devres function.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f8a096059fc5f719301d314e5d7451f1bab5032a) as well

Answer (score 0):

A portable way is using pci_iomap() function. It's automatically determine type of BAR and works with MMIO and PIO. Instead of writeb()/readb() you should use ioread*()/iowrite*()